# Error running a Bevy game in browser: "WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="wbindgen_placeholder" error: module is not an object or function"

Tags: rust, webassembly, webgl2, wasm-bindgen, bevy

I am trying to run a game I built with Bevy and Rust in the browser. Bevy started supporting WebGL2 from version 0.11.0, and I am using this version. I have compiled my Rust code to WebAssembly using `wasm-pack build --target web`.

However, when I try to initialize the WebAssembly module in my HTML file, I get the following error:

```
WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="__wbindgen_placeholder__" error: module is not an object or function
```

Here is the JavaScript code I am using to initialize the WebAssembly module:

```
    import init, { run } from './game.js';

async function main() {
    await init('./game.wasm');
    run();
}

main();
```

In main.rs I have my run function with the export defined like:

```
#[wasm_bindgen]
pub fn run() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
    //initialize more systems and resources 
}
```

I have verified my paths are correct, and I am serving the files using the Live Server extension in VSCode. I am using the latest version of chrome and rust on popOS.

I have also checked the Bevy documentation and examples, but I couldn't find any specific guidance on this issue.

Does anyone know what could be causing this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Can WebGL2 be compiled to webassembly? Or what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compile a `bevy` application to wasm using [`wasm-pack`](https://rustwasm.github.io/wasm-pack/) you need to do it a bit different than usual.

First of all there is no need to add the `#[wasm_bindgen]` attribute anywhere in your rust code (e.g. no need to explicetly depend on `wasm-bindgen`).

To **build your project** for the `wasm32-unknown-unknown` target, run:

```
cargo build --release --target wasm32-unknown-unknown
```

and after that create the JavaScript bindings using `wasm-pack` and the binary built in the previous step:

```
wasm-bindgen --out-dir out --target web target/wasm32-unknown-unknown/release/game.wasm
```

Lastly serve such an `index.html` with a *http-server* of your choice:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bevy Game</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <style>
        body {
            background: linear-gradient(135deg,
                    white 0%,
                    white 49%,
                    black 49%,
                    black 51%,
                    white 51%,
                    white 100%);
            background-repeat: repeat;
            background-size: 20px 20px;
        }

        canvas {
            background-color: white;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<script type="module">
    import init from './out/game.wasm'
    init()
</script>

</html>
```

with the relevant part of course being:

```html
<script type="module">
    import init from './out/game.wasm'
    init()
</script>
```

I have a full repository where this workflow is set up over [here](https://github.com/FrankenApps/bevy_meshtext_sample/tree/master#wasm).